# Python speech recognition working very slow and has much time lag

Tags: python, machine-learning, speech-recognition

how to make this speech recognition listen and respond faster. it recognizes accurately but has much time lag and delay someone pls provide solution for this or if their might be some threshold settings by which we can limit its hearing time in particular iteration

following is the code i m using:

```
def speak(text):
    tts=gTTS(text=text,lang="en")
    date_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M%S")
    filename="hello"+date_string+".mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)

def getAudio():    
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio=r.listen(source)
        said=""

        try:
            said=r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except:
            print("sorry can not understand")
    return said

while True: 

    text=getAudio()

    if "hello" in text:
        speak("hello there,how are you")

    if "your name" in text:
        speak("my name is bot")

    if "quit" in text:
        speak("Goodbye see you again!")
        break
```